# RectClear Nor working for HTML5 Canvas Scale Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, canvas

**My Question**:  What is causing the HTML5 Canvas clearRect method to fail to work as expected in the situation described below, and is there anything I can do to fix it (without adding another third party library to my project)?

**In Short**: I am animating various scaling operations on an HTML5 canvas.  I am using JQuery to process those animations in order to utilize the readily available easing functions.  Under certain conditions, the clearRect method does not appear to clear the canvas fully.

**More Detailed** I have set up a buffer canvas which contains the image data I want to draw onto a main display canvas.  Each time I need to update the scale or rotation of the display canvas, I clear the main canvas, make those changes to the display canvas, and then draw the buffer canvas onto the display canvas.

When very specific animation sequences are being used (easeOutElastic for example), and the scaling is at a point during the final part of the easing function (in this case where the scaling has reversed direction), the canvas seems not to be clearing.

**What I've Tried**
I have tried the following approaches, unsuccessfully:

- Rounding off the values produced by the JQuery animation before scaling with them (i.e.: toFixed(1))
- Tracking the values produced by the JQuery animation and skipping the scale operation for values that did not change significantly
- Injecting an extra setTimeout(fn, 0) into each animation step to see if the browser was being overtaxed.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem (which I have attempted on IE 11, Chrome 37, and FF 32):

http://jsfiddle.net/pae9n00n/21/

*(The third test demonstrates the problem)*

```
//Easy refs
var canvasBuff = $("#canvasBuff")[0];
var ctxBuff = canvasBuff.getContext("2d");
var canvasMain = $("#canvasMain")[0];
var ctxMain = canvasMain.getContext("2d");
var offsetX = 64;
var offsetY = 64;

//Setup
setupBufferCanvas();
setupMainCanvas();
refreshMainCanvas();

$("#butTest1").click(function(){ doTest1(); });
$("#butTest2").click(function(){ doTest2(); });
$("#butTest3").click(function(){ doTest3(); });

$("#butReset").click(function(){ 

    var l = -1 * offsetX;
    var t = -1 * offsetY;
    ctxMain.clearRect(l, t, canvasMain.width, canvasMain.height);

    ctxMain.restore();
    refreshMainCanvas(); 
    ctxMain.save();
});

//=======================
// doTest1
//=======================
function doTest1(){
    //No Problems
    animateScale(2, 2, 1000, "linear", null);
};    

//=======================
// doTest2
//=======================
function doTest2(){
//No Problems
animateScale(2, 2, 800, "linear", function(){
    animateScale(.5, .5, 200, "linear", null);
});
};    

//=======================
// doTest3
//=======================
function doTest3(){
    //Problem
    animateScale(2, 2, 1000, "easeOutElastic", null);
};    

//=======================
// setupBufferCanvas
//=======================
function setupBufferCanvas(){
    //Prep the buffer canvas
    canvasBuff.width=128;
    canvasBuff.height=128;

    ctxBuff.fillStyle = "rgba(74,142,196,1)";
    ctxBuff.fillRect(32, 32, 64, 64);

    ctxBuff.lineWidth = 4;
    ctxBuff.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    ctxBuff.strokeRect(32, 32, 64, 64);
};

//=======================
// setupMainCanvas
//=======================
function setupMainCanvas(){
    canvasMain.width=128;
    canvasMain.height=128;
    ctxMain.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
    ctxMain.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
    scaleMainCanvas(.5,.5); //scale to half
    ctxMain.save();
};

//=======================
// clearMainCanvas
//=======================
function clearMainCanvas(){
    var l = -1 * offsetX;
    var t = -1 * offsetY;
    ctxMain.clearRect(l, t, canvasMain.width, canvasMain.height);
};

//=======================
// refreshMainCanvas
//=======================
function refreshMainCanvas(){
    var l = -1 * offsetX;
    var t = -1 * offsetY;
    ctxMain.clearRect(l, t, canvasMain.width, canvasMain.height);
    ctxMain.drawImage(canvasBuff, l, t);
};

//=======================
// scaleMainCanvas
//=======================
function scaleMainCanvas(x, y){
    var l = -1 * offsetX;
    var t = -1 * offsetY;
    ctxMain.clearRect(l, t, canvasMain.width, canvasMain.height);
    ctxMain.scale(x, y)
    ctxMain.drawImage(canvasBuff, l, t);
};

//=======================
// animateScale
//=======================
function animateScale(x, y, duration, easing, callback){
    var ani$ = $({x:1, y:1});
    ani$.animate({x:x, y:y},{
        duration:duration,
        easing:easing,
        step: function(){
            ctxMain.save();
            scaleMainCanvas(ani$[0].x, ani$[0].y);
            ctxMain.restore();
        },
        complete: function(){
            scaleMainCanvas(x, y);
            if (callback){ callback(); }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**: The error, unsurprisingly, was my own mistake.  In an effort to keep the scale operations from accumulating, I save() and restore() the canvas scale before and after each rendering.  The problem here is that I end up clearing the canvas against the previous size, which is always the starting scale (which is smaller than the current drawing scale in this case).

*The problem is obfuscated during increasing scale operations as we draw over everything anyway.*

I hacked a solution into the Fiddle. Its probably not the ideal long term solution. but does confirm the error and the cause:

http://jsfiddle.net/pae9n00n/24/

Fix was applied in this method:

```
//=======================
// scaleMainCanvas
//=======================
function scaleMainCanvas(x, y, useFix){
    var l = -1 * offsetX;
    var t = -1 * offsetY;

    ctxMain.clearRect(l, t, canvasMain.width, canvasMain.height);

    ctxMain.scale(x, y);

    if (useFix){
        //Not a great solution, but it illustartes my error
        ctxMain.clearRect(l, t, canvasMain.width, canvasMain.height);
    }

    ctxMain.drawImage(canvasBuff, l, t);
};
```

Comment: I'd also like to add that I'm starting to realize that using save() and restore() in this way is a bad idea.  It creates potential conflicts with other, simultaneous operations that might be sensitive to such wholesale changes against the context.  I plan to start tracking the scale changes manually, and reverse them explicitly as needed.  I think that's a more sustainable approach.